# Get values from an array stored inside a map

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I have a map with integer keys and corresponding values of arrays of strings.  I want to get a get a value out of that array from inside the map and am having a heck of a time doing this.  My searches haven't yielded anything useful other than the recommendation to 'wrap it' and I'm really not sure what that means!  Here is an example:

```
Map myTasks = new HashMap();

myTasks.put(1, new String[] {"cake"});
myTasks.put(15, new String[] {"bake"});

String myString = myTasks.get(1)[0];  // This doesn't work.
```

So I have picked up that myTasks.get(1) returns an object.  How do I get a string value out of that object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Generics for it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, String[]> myTasks = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();

    myTasks.put(1, new String[] {"cake"});
    myTasks.put(15, new String[] {"bake"});

    String myString = myTasks.get(1)[0];
    System.out.println(myString);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem in your code is, you are trying to access an object as array directly.

Try this-

```
Map myTasks = new HashMap();

myTasks.put(1, new String[] {"cake"});
myTasks.put(15, new String[] {"bake"});

String[] myString = (String[]) myTasks.get(1);
System.out.println(myString[0]);
```

All you have to do is typecast the object.

Best practice is to use-

```
Map<Integer, String[]> myTasks = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
```

Instead of `Map myTasks = new HashMap();` with which you don't need to typecast.

Answer (score 1):

Add generic type:

```
Map<Integer, String[]> myTasks = new HashMap<Integer, String[]>();
```